# How to get shared prefs in Adapter class, Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I Get data from firebase into a recycler view, In my Adapter class I want to get a Data which is stored in my Shared Prefs, How can I get the Data which is in my Shared Prefs into my Firebase Adapter Activity !

MY ADAPTER CLASS

```
public class Chat_Adapter extends 
   FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat_Model,Chat_Adapter.myViewHolder> {

    public Chat_Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat_Model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Chat_Model model) {
        holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
        holder.uname.setText(model.getUname());
        holder.msg.setText(model.getMsg());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView uname, date,msg;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            uname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.named);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a data coming from my Database which (model.getUname), What i want to do is to my original name from my Shared Prefs and check if (model.getUname == myname).

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I just want to get a data from shared prefs but i dont know how to... I want to get the data in this class code above

Comment: So it is a question that is more related to SharedPreferences rather than Firebase, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Context inside onCreateViewHolder() method and save it in your field variable and then use it inside onBindViewHolder() and get shared prefs there

```
public class Chat_Adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat_Model, Chat_Adapter.myViewHolder> {
private Context context;

public Chat_Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat_Model> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Chat_Model model) {

    //here is your shared pref
    SharedPreferences your_shared_pref_name = context.getSharedPreferences("YOUR_SHARED_PREF_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.uname.setText(model.getUname());
    holder.msg.setText(model.getMsg());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);
    context = parent.getContext();
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView uname, date, msg;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        uname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.named);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    }
  }
}
```